# How to map a list of array with selective index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, fso

I have a list of Array with filenames and filepath. Is group into a list of array.

Example :

```
**var files = [filenameA, filenameB, filenameC, filepathA, filepathB, filepathC]**
```

I need to map them and convert them to -->

```
var remapfiles = {[filenameA,filepathA],[filenameB,filepathB], [filenameC,filepathC]}
```

The reason it was compile in **`files`** it was extracted using an SDK function where it will retrieve all filesnames and path.

How should i map/sort this to get **`remapfiles`** result and to log ? Please advice.

Comment: can you show a sample of `filenameA` and `filepathA`? you can use reduce to do this

Comment: Hi@boxdox, this is the sample of path 

'"FileA.xlsm,FileB.xlsm,FileC .xlsm,C:\\Bla\\Bla\\EXCEL_FOLDER\\FileA.xlsm,C:\\Bla\\Bla\\EXCEL_FOLDER\\FileB.xlsm,C:\\Bla\\Bla\\EXCEL_FOLDER\\FileC.xlsm,'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming filepaths always come after filenames, you can try:

```js
let files = ['filenameA', 'filenameB', 'filenameC', 'filepathA', 'filepathB', 'filepathC']
let remapfiles = [];
for (let i = 0; i < files.length/2; i++) {
  remapfiles.push([files[i], files[files.length/2+i]])
}
console.log(remapfiles)
```

Comment: Thanks! it works but there's slight changes need to handle increasing of files. 

`code`
    let files = ['filenameA', 'filenameB', 'filenameC', 'filepathA', 'filepathB', 'filepathC']
    let remapfiles = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length/2; i++) {
      remapfiles.push([files[i], files[files.length/2+i]])
    }
    console.log(remapfiles)
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Learning Mathematics

```html
let files = ['filenameA', 'filenameB', 'filenameC', 'filepathA', 'filepathB', 'filepathC']
let remapfiles = [];
for (let i = 0; i < files.length/2; i++) {
  remapfiles.push([files[i], files[files.length/2+i]])
}
console.log(remapfiles)
```

This code works.